# Unable to add SWC file to Flex Library Build Path in Flash Builder

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, swc

I'm looking at Flash Builder for my next project. I'm following some tutorials, yet I keep getting stuck at the same part. The tutorials I am following tell me to add a SWC files (containing my art) and should be in a library project.

I can create the library project and use it as a reference in my application. However, when I try to add the SWC file to the "Flex Library Build Path" the OK button does nothing. The same happens if I try to add a SWC or SWC Folder.

I' m using Flash Builder 4.6 (trial version) if that makes any difference. Below is a screenshot of the window that I am talking about in case I'm not very clear.

[image: Flash Builder Library Build Path]

Comment: Did you want to add the .swc to your `Library` project or to your main project? It looks like you have selected the properties menu and hence build path of your `Library` rather than a Flex/Air project?

Comment: Is there a valid SWC at the location specified in the screenshot?  Was that SWC created w/ a Flash Builder Library Project [and or the command line Flex Tools?]  Or was the SWC created in Flash Pro?

Comment: I want to add the SWC to my Library project, this was I can keep my "main" project clean. There is a SWC at the location in the screen shot and the SWC was created using Flash Professions CS5.5

Comment: The issue is probably that it is a Flash Pro SWC; but I'm just guessing.  If the SWC is full of library assets; then you should embed it into your library project ( http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html ).  If it's full of AS3 code; then you may try to take the code and re-create it in Flash Builder.

Comment: Okay I'll give that a go. It's got movie clips in it. If I can't get this to work then I'd be happy to show you the issue via TeamViewer... Maybe I'm just doing it wrong

Comment: Something must be wrong with my installation... As now I cant reference my Library from my Main Project =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has also happened to me.
There is workaround - just place SWC into /libs directory of your project and perform clean. SWCs there will be loaded automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the folder to the Workspace's linked resources. In Flash Builder, go to menu Windows > Preferences > General > Workspace > Linked Resources, and add a new path variable to the component directory. After this, the component can be added to the project's Flex Library path.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug of flash builder. It has also happened to me. And I can not choose the output path in fb....

I found a way, first, delete this project, delete evrey thing fb created itself except the source code, then u can swith ur fb to a new workspace, add creat a new project, u will see that u can add the swc file now.finally,switch back to the workspace u worked with before......